# No module named 'discord' Что делать? Хелп

Tags: python, бот, discord.py

Писал простенького бота для дискорд в Sublime text, как всегда в папке с ботом создаю Bat файл для коннекта

@echo off
py Wooolfix.py
pause

Запускаю, и получаю:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "Wooolfix.py", line 1, in 
> import discordModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'discord'

Как пофиксить?

[image: Скрин]

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Также возможно, если вы переустанавливали Python, у вас просто нет этой библиотеки.

Comment: pip install discord.py - введи это в свою консоль

Comment: Пожалуйста, будьте осторожны: вы показали токен вашего бота. Рекомендую вам его немедленно сбросить, иначе могут возникнуть проблемы.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте написать в командную строку `py -m pip install discord.py`. И в следующий раз скройте токен бота, а сейчас просто смените его на сайте https://discord.com/developers/applications :)

Answer (score -1):

У вас отсутствует библиотека "`discord.py`".

Вот как её установить:

```bash
pip install discord.py
```

Если выдаёт ошибку, что команда `pip` не найдена, то вводим эту команду и затем повторяем предыдущий процесс:

```
# Для Windows
py -m pip install -U pip
```

Comment: В документации к этой библиотеке написано, что лучше её не устанавливать, а вы почему-то предлагаете её устанавливать. Нехорошо